# Installing R on RHEL6

Tags: r, linux, redhat

I am unable to install R in RHEL 6.

1)

```
 rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

"package epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm" is already installed.

2)  After running, sudo yum update

```
sudo yum install R
```

Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, kabi, presto, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager, tmprepo, verify,
              : versionlock

```
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.

Loading support for Red Hat kernel ABI

Setting up Install Process

No package R available.

Error: Nothing to do
```

3) Based on various previous posts, I checked if rhel optional is enabled:

```
yum repolist all
```

Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, kabi, presto, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, security, subscription-manager, tmprepo, verify,
: versionlock

```
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.

Loading support for Red Hat kernel ABI

repo id                                   repo name                                                                         status

rhel-source                               Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server - x86_64 - Source                                disabled

rhel-source-beta                          Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server Beta - x86_64 - Source                           disabled

rhel-x86_64-server-6                      Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (v. 6 for 64-bit x86_64)                          enabled: 18,009

rhel-x86_64-server-extras-6               RHEL Server Extras (v. 6 for 64-bit x86_64)                                       enabled:     51

rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6             RHEL Server Optional (v. 6 64-bit x86_64)                                         enabled: 10,255
```

Adding one more piece of information - not sure if it is key.

As per the note below, a flag needs to be changed to 1. 
https://bluehatrecord.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/installing-r-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-5/

```
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo

[rhel-6-server-optional-rpms]
...
enabled = 1
```

However, the file is empty except for a few header statements. Not sure if it being empty is the cause.

Any step that I have missed?

Comment: Have you considered the instructions here?: https://bluehatrecord.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/installing-r-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-5/

Comment: Yes.     redhat.repo didn't have any text content within it , however yum repolist all shows RHEL Server Optional is enabled.

Comment: The repo id is a bit different from the bluehatrecord post ..not sure if it makes a difference.